# socket_getpeername() "Transport endpoint is not connected" warning

Tags: php, sockets

A  have problem retrieving remote socket IP and port number.
During following procedure:

```
$master_socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//socket_bind(), socket_listen(), socket_accept()
socket_getpeername($client_socket, $client_address, $client_port);
```

This works fine on localhost(WAMP), but in production it generates warning:

`PHP Warning:  socket_getpeername(): unable to retrieve peer name [107]: Transport endpoint is not connected in ...`

This is strange, because `$client_socket` is a proper socket resource, other socket functions such as `socket_read()` perform as they should; `socket_getsockname()` also works, binding local IP and port number to assigned variables.

Searching the web gives nothing. Does anybody know what could be the reason of such warning?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the traffic. Have you tried to investigate this using wireshark? Also you should not mix `socket_getpeername()` with `socket_getsockname()`, they are not the same

Comment: The problem is that this is a server-side daemon, and I need to analyze server side traffic, which is not possible for now. I understand that those functions are different, it was just for the heads up.

Comment: use `sudo tcpdump -iINTERFACE -s65535 -wtraffic.pcap` on server to sniff the traffic. You can analyze traffic.pcap with wireshark afterwards. However, you can sniff the communication on client as well